# cumulative improvement score

Tags: sql

I have ne table of student score

| date | college_id | challenge_id | student_id | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-01 | C11219 | CH10101 | S1000 | 80 |
| 2020-10-01 | C11219 | CH10101 | S1001 | 55 |
| 2020-10-02 | C11219 | CH10102 | S1000 | 87 |
| 2020-10-02 | C11219 | CH10102 | S1001 | 42 |
| 2020-10-03 | C11219 | CH10103 | S1000 | 95 |
| 2020-10-03 | C11219 | CH10103 | S1001 | 50 |
| 2020-10-01 | C11220 | CH10101 | S2000 | 57 |
| 2020-10-01 | C11220 | CH10101 | S2001 | 84 |
| 2020-10-02 | C11220 | CH10102 | S2000 | 17 |
| 2020-10-02 | C11220 | CH10102 | S2001 | 34 |
| 2020-10-03 | C11220 | CH10103 | S2000 | 75 |
| 2020-10-03 | C11220 | CH10103 | S2001 | 12 |

I want to identify students who had a positive cumulative improvement in their scores. For example: Student S1000 of college C11219 has a positive cumulative improvement score of 15 calculated as (87 - 80) + (95 - 87).
Whereas, Student S1001 of college C11219 has a negative cumulative improvement score of -5 calculated as (42 - 55) + (50 - 42).

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: If MySQL - specify precise version.

Comment: How is <cscore> related? ("_CSCore is a free .NET audio library. It includes various features for working with audio (like playing and recording sounds, applying effects, encoding and decoding audio files, ...)._")

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result. And show us your current query attempt. (I.e. [mcve].)

Comment: What is student identifying data - `student_id` or `(college_id,student_id)`?

Comment: i am using sqlm student_id is identifying data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cumulative score does not use intermediate score values.

| date | ScoreName | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-01 | StartingScore | 80 |
| 2020-10-02 | Intermediary1 | 87 |
| 2020-10-03 | Intermediary2 | 95 |
| 2020-10-04 | Intermediary3 | 50 |
| 2020-10-05 | Intermediary4 | 55 |
| 2020-10-06 | EndScore | 95 |

Based on your example, the cummulative score would be :

```
(87-80)+(95-87)+(50-95)+(55-50)+(95-55)=15
```

Or we could write is as

```
(Intermediary1-StartingScore)+(Intermediary2-Intermediary1)+(Intermediary3-Intermediary2)+(Intermediary4-Intermediary3)+(EndScore-Intermediary4)
```

which if we open up the parentheses, is

```
EndScore-StartingScore => 95-80=15
```

Thus, what we need are the first and last score for each student ordered by date. We get that using window functions in a common table expression that we later on filter. I assume the student is identified using the tuple (college_id,student_id)

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        college_id,
        student_id,
        FIRST_VALUE(score) OVER (PARTITION BY college_id,student_id ORDER BY date ASC) as StartScore,
        FIRST_VALUE(score) OVER (PARTITION BY college_id,student_id ORDER BY date DESC) as EndScore
FROM YourTable
)
SELECT college_id,student_id 
FROM CTE 
WHERE EndScore-StartScore > 0
```

Comment: Hey @GabrielDurac, 
 i want to show score value as  improvement_score but while adding score coulumn i am getting error or geeting full record

Comment: What database are you using MySql or SQL Server ? and what version ?

Comment: WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        college_id,
        student_id,
        FIRST_VALUE(score) OVER (PARTITION BY college_id,student_id ORDER BY date ASC) as StartScore,
        FIRST_VALUE(score) OVER (PARTITION BY college_id,student_id ORDER BY date DESC) as EndScore
FROM your_table
)
SELECT college_id,student_id, EndScore-StartScore as improvement_score
FROM CTE 
WHERE EndScore-StartScore > 0  this will display the result, thank you for your help

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6e066/3

Not sure what your issue is. In the future, if you need help on SO it is best to create a table and sample data on either sqlfiddle.com or https://dbfiddle.uk. People are more willing to help if you make it easier for them :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEAD` analytical function and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
select student_id, max(score) - min(score) as cum_score from
(select t.*, lead(t.score) over (partition by t.student_id order by t.date) as ldscore 
  from your_Table t)
group by student_id
having count(case when score > ldscore then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: this query is not giving positive value in student id = S1001 is negetive cumilitve but due to this max & min function its nt giving value as expected